# Enable POST method to Laravel Folklore\GraphQL or enable GET method in react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5, graphql, react-apollo

I try connect React with Laravel's Folklore\GraphQL.

In ReactJS I have this code ind `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, createNetworkInterface } from 'react-apollo';
import Devices from './components/Devices.js'

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphiql',
    opts: {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        mode: 'no-cors',
    },
});
const client = new ApolloClient({ networkInterface });

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Devices />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And in `Devices.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

class Devices extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return(
            <div>Hello</div>
        );
    }
}

const query = gql`
{
    devices {
        id_device,
        name,
        type,
    }
}
`;
export default graphql(query)(Devices);
```

But show the error:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphiql 405 (Method Not Allowed)

and if I add to `method:'GET'` in `opts` show the following error:

> Unhandled (in react-apollo) Error: Network error: Failed to execute
>   'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

How can I added the method POST to Folklore\GraphQL? 
How can I set the method to GET to ApolloClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was my, because y put the URL of the interface of GraphQL. The URL correct is http://127.0.0.1:8000/**graphql**